# Connecting Contacts when Email Addresses Match but Subscriber Keys do not in Multi-Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, filters, sync, subscriber-key

Trying to get ahead of the curve at my Company and we are in the process of connecting multiple CRMs to our Marketing Cloud. So my question is how do we connect contacts that we know are the same person, but because they are going to piped in from different CRMs might have different Subscriber Keys? We have been using Marketing Cloud purely as a ESP, but are working towards connecting in our various BUs.

```
EmailAddress         | SubscriberKey    | BU1   | BU2
---------------------------------------------------------
user0001@email.com   | ABC123DEF456     | True  | False
user0001@email.com   | GHI789JKL012     | False | True
```

Above is obviously an example... but point is the same person is doing business with two seperate BUs and are being piped into Marketing Cloud from two seperate CRMs. Is it as simple as finding a way to connect them EmailAddress = EmailAddress in an SQL statement?

We are pushing for being intelligent on cross-selling between our BUs. If you need more information just ask, thank you!

Comment: Marketing Cloud identifies contacts by their SubscriberKey (Lead/Contact Id). You could potentially use SQL to create suppression lists and the likes, but it's never going to function as a Single Customer View. SQL can certainly join all the duplicate email addresses together, but to what end?

Comment: Having multiple Sales Cloud Orgs qualifies your company for Customer360 Data Manager. This tool is being designed to help precisely with challenges like having a common view on multiple separate orgs. Check what you can find online and speak to your account executive about that before trying to solve this with Marketing Cloud.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=c360_basics.htm&type=5